# Prove that $(A\oplus C) \cup (B - C) \nsubseteq (A \oplus B) \cup C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Prove that $(A\oplus C) \cup (B - C) \nsubseteq (A \oplus B) \cup C$

In the picture below, I can see easily that $(A\oplus C) \cup (B - C) \nsubseteq (A \oplus B) \cup C$ .

But, Venn's diagram is not enough to show that. I need to give an example with $A,B,C$ sets. and I can find 3 sets that will prove that if I "guess" many times, but if I take a step back,

I have no idea how can I 'logically' zoom out and check how to construct those 3 sets easily. I did emphasize "2" ,"4" and "5" as you can see in the picture below, but it does not tell me much right now, because I lack the knowledge of how to use it.

Can you explain me how can I construct sets easily based on the Venn's diagram I painted and based on the "numbers" 2,4,5?  It'd be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is $A \oplus C$ for arbitrary sets? I'm only familiar with that symbol in the context of algrebra.

Comment: @paul sinclair simmetry difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every site I looked up on symmetric difference (to see if this was common symbolism I was unaware of) listed a different set of symbols as "commonly used" for it. (Yours did appear in Wikipedia's list.) Personally, I prefer $\triangle$, which is the most common.

What I am having trouble understanding is your question. You have everything there already, so where is your confusion?

$$A = \{1, 2, 4, 5\}$$
$$B = \{2, 3, 5, 6\}$$
$$C = \{4, 5, 6, 7\}$$
$$A \oplus C = \{ 1, 2, 6, 7\}$$
$$B \setminus C = \{ 2, 3 \}$$
$$A \oplus C \cup B \setminus C = \{1, 2, 3, 6, 7\}$$
$$A \oplus B = \{ 1, 3, 4, 6\}$$
$$A \oplus B \cup C = \{ 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$$

Since $2 \in A \oplus C \cup B \setminus C$, but $2 \notin A \oplus B \cup C$, we have that $$(A\oplus C) \cup (B \setminus C) \nsubseteq (A \oplus B) \cup C$$

(The fact $5 \in  A \oplus B \cup C$ but not in $A \oplus C \cup B \setminus C$ is immaterial to the question, since it does not ask about $A \oplus B \cup C$ being a subset of $A \oplus C \cup B \setminus C$.)

Comment: Hahaha! I'm so stupid. Thank you so much!